# Does downvote cause reputation changes here?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I recently had a -1 reputation change for **downvoting** [downvoted question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19055/is-it-safer-to-use-less-heard-of-software-than-popular-software/19068#19068)

I wish to clarify two things:

1. What made my **reputation**(-1 reputation) change?
2. Does the downvote lead to reputation loss(as usually downvoting doesn't lose reputation on other stackexchange sites)?

Answer (score 9):

1. Downvoting an *answer* causes -1 to the voter's rep (and -2 the poster).
2. Downvoting a *question* does not affect the voter's rep (but -2 to the poster).
3. Downvoting *anything* on **Meta.Sec.SE** does not affect anyone's rep, neither the poster nor the voter (and neither does upvoting).

This is exactly the same as on any other SE site. (except for Meta.SO, which has it's own rep separate from SO).

Comment: The help center insists on how [voting is important](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). However I just realized that downvoting an answer causes a loss of reputation of the voter. Is it therefore considered as a bad practice to downvote [dangerous answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86470/how-can-i-explain-self-signed-certificates-to-users/86471#86471)?

Comment: @GZBK In general - if the answer is genuinely dangerous (and we do get a fair bit of those here), as opposed to just wrong or "I don't like it" - then after you downvote, please **flag it**. We do try to remove the really dangerous ones (unless it is sufficiently downvoted to leave a stronger signal against it :-) ). After the answer is deleted, you get your downvote-point returned.